# Build not succed in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

when i try flutter build apk --release , i get following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* Where:                                                                
Build file 

'/Users/flutter/Documents/project_name/android/
build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:                                                      
A problem occurred evaluating root project 
'android'.                   
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.                        
> Removing unused resources requires unused code 
shrinking to be turned on. See 
http://d.android.com/r/tools/shrink-resources.html 
for more information.

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack 
trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 33s
```

When i build for ios, i gets output. but having very large size around 400 mb.

How to resolve all these issues.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the issue but as per the error logs, you have to remove all the unused resource from code and then you have to set in gradle.

```
android {
...
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
```

Also, if you will remove unused resouces, It will reduce the size of the iOS build.

Happy coding...

Comment: thanks man , it works for android. but it is only for android, right? so how it reduce size of ios build

Comment: Yes, correct. But after removing unused resources, you can also reduce the size of ios build.